# Getting error even if file is present inside that directory using PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am facing one issue. I am using `class.phpmailer.php` to send the email using PHP but in the code I am getting some error which are given below.

**Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /var/www/example.com/public_html/spesh/mobileapi/sendmymail.php on line 5**

Here I am explaining my code below.

> mobileapi/sendmymail.php:

```
<?php   
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    echo 'hello';exit;
    /*$body='<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title> HTML5 : Hello World Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>
            Hey there!
            </p>
            </body>
            </html>';
    $mail->SetFrom('info@thespesh.com', 'Info The Spesh');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("info@thespesh.com","Info The Spesh");
    $mail->Subject    = "Sending Test Mail";
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address ='subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com' ;
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
    if($mail->Send()) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }*/
?>
```

I have also `class.phpmailer.php` file inside that `mobileapi` directory but still I am getting the above error. Here I need to clear this error and send mail successfully.

Comment: Check the file permission. It should be readable..

Comment: What version of `PHPMailer` you are using ? It has namespace in latest verions. So it should be like `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;`

Comment: You can download latest version from here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php

Comment: @Alexey : I am using the version `* PHPMailer - PHP email creation and transport class.
 * PHP Version 5.5.`.

Comment: @Jasbir : Yes it has read permission

Comment: try to use include instead of require then..

Comment: You should not be doing any new development on PHP 5.5; it's no longer supported. Switching to `include` is pointless - it just means it will fail when you try to create the instance instead. The namespaced PHPMailer has a different filename, so you are using an old version. I can only suggest you upgrade everything and load the files as it says in the readme.